Is it correct to say "I signed my daughter up for first grade"?
In Oxford dictionary, we have this

sign up (for something)
​to arrange to do a course of study by adding your name to the list of
people doing it
You can sign up online for language classes.

Say, my daughter is 6. She can not read or write and she will go to first grade this year.
I will take her to school but I can not say "my daughter signed up for first grade" because I am the one who signed, not her but she is the one who study there.
There is another phrase in Oxford dictionary

sign up phrasal verb
sign on/up | sign somebody <> on/up
​to sign a form or contract which says that you agree to do a job or
become a soldier; to persuade somebody to sign a form or contract like
this SYNONYM enlist
He signed on for five years in the army.
The company has signed up three top models for the fashion show.

I can say "I signed up my daughter for first grade" but my daughter is not joining the army or having a job.

sign up

To enlist or enroll oneself or someone in something. A noun or pronoun can be used between "sign" and "up." My mother signed me up for piano lessons on the weekend.


It's certainly not incorrect but I believe "enroll" would be much more common in AME.

For me, it seems slightly odd, since it seems like she will only take 1st grade.  You won't need to sign her up again in a years time for 2nd grade.  British English might have "Put her name down for school)

The sentence in the title sounds fine to me. "First grade" is a little more specific than "school", that's all.

Short answer: Yes.
It's completely valid to speak of signing someone else up. You might sign for someone else because they are too young to do it themselves, because they have mental disabilities that make them incapable ("I signed my father up for the nursing home"), because you are signing for him without his consent ("As a joke, we signed Bill up for the army. Just wait until he gets his orders to show up for basic training!"), etc.
